# jQuery changed "href" value but doesn't display correctly afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to the website and hope I am asking the question correctly. I've looked for answers around the web but can't find any solution.

Basically, I have a big picture and underneath a small picture. The desired outcome is when the small picture is clicked, it should change places with the big picture (small one becomes big and big becomes small). Also when the picture is in the #big  I have a zoom script that uses bigger version of the picture. This is my script changing the attributes of the  and  tag

```
$('#small img:nth-of-type(1)').click(function(){
        if ($('#med1').attr('src') == 'images/m-<?php echo $src; ?>.jpg') {
              $('#big1').attr('href','images/<?php echo $src; ?>_2.jpg');
              $('#med1 ').attr('src','images/m-<?php echo $src; ?>_2.jpg');
              $('#small img:nth-of-type(1)').attr('src','images/m-<?php echo $src; ?>.jpg');
              console.log($('#big1').attr('href'))
        } else {
                 $('#big1').attr('href','images/<?php echo $src; ?>.jpg');
                 $('#med1 ').attr('src','images/m-<?php echo $src; ?>.jpg');
                 $('#small img:nth-of-type(1)').attr('src','images/m-<?php echo $src; ?>_2.jpg');
                 console.log($('#big1').attr('href'))                               
                }               
});
```

I used console.log() to check if the script was passing the right parameter to the  tag and it is passing the correct one. But for whatever reason it doesn't work (zoom image doesn't change). Here is the code in the  containing the big picture and the zoom ones:

```
<div id="big"> 
  <?php 
        echo "<a href=\"images/"  .$src.  ".jpg\" class=\"zoom\" id=\"big1\"><img src=\"images/m-". $src. ".jpg\" class=\"big\" id=\"med1\"></a>" ; 
        echo "<a href=\"images/"  .$src. "_1.jpg\" class=\"zoom1\" id=\"big2\"><img src=\"images/m-".   $src. "_1.jpg\" class=\"big\" id=\"med2\"></a>" ; 
    ?>
</div>
```

Tell me if you need live demo to see it or any other information. I'm really lost on this one. The script successfully changes the pictures and if we can trust the console.log() it successfully changes the href of the  tag, but visually the zoom image doesn't change. Please help!

EDIT: this is the live demo : 
http://look.pgmtplovdiv.info/kami/modeli.php?k_nomer=777

Comment: We need live demo to find what you want really! :)

Comment: I edited my post with the link. Ask if you need more information

Comment: But it works, where is the problem in it?

Comment: it doesn't work correctly. When you click the small picture on the bottom, it changes places with the big one. But when you hoover the "new" big picture on the left that has just changed it zooms the old picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoom functionality is activated with this sentence: `$('a.zoom').easyZoom();`. When you update your image you must update zoom functionality too. You can try with this after updating the href: `$('#big1').easyZoom();`.

Comment: Thanks man, that is how it work. I was almost sure that this was the issue but didn't know how to solve it. Didn't think that I can just call it again. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

It is because your easyzoom.js file is loading a copy of the image to display in the zoom at the time you initially call it.  The mouseover then uses that image.  You'll need to change that.

Comment: How can I recall the easyzoom.js or switch the image? I tough this might be a problem but then I saw that the console.log() successfully changes the href attribute

Comment: As Fernando suggested I should have just recalled the function. Thanks for the help anyway